# Making a particular word in sentences bold but not highlighting the entire sentence before ", Lead Bookrunner"

Tags: excel, vba, cell

Sentence 1: Uber, $9.37MM Equity. Stifel Nicolaus, Lead Bookrunner.(I want to bold characters after "." and before ", Lead Bookrunner" and also the starting character before "," i.e. name of the bank and company name which is Stifel Nicolaus & Uber in this case. Also "." appears in 9.37MM
Sentence 2:  Google, $750MM Credit deal. JP Morgan, Lead Bookrunner.

My code:

```
Set Where = Range("P2", Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  With Where
    .Value = .Value
    .Font.Bold = False
  End With
  For Each This In Where
    i = InStr(This, ", Lead Bookrunner.")
    If i = 0 Then i = Len(This) + 1
    This.Characters(1, i - 1).Font.Bold = True
  Next
For Each This In Where
    i = InStr(This, ".")
    If i = 0 Then i = Len(This) + 1
    This.Characters(1, i - 1).Font.Bold = False
  Next
For Each This In Where
    i = InStr(This, ",")
    If i = 0 Then i = Len(This) + 1
    This.Characters(1, i - 1).Font.Bold = True
  Next
```

The result I am getting through my code:  **Uber**, $9.**37MM Equity. Stifel Nicolaus**, Lead Bookrunner.
Result what I want: **Uber**, $9.37MM Equity. **Stifel Nicolaus**, Lead Bookrunner.

Comment: Will the format always be like `TEXT COMMA TEXT FULLSTOP TEXT COMMA TEXT(Lead Bookrunner)`? **EX 1.**

`TEXT (Uber) COMMA TEXT($9.37MM Equity) FULLSTOP TEXT (Stifel Nicolaus) COMMA TEXT(Lead Bookrunner)`

**EX 2.**

`TEXT (Google) COMMA TEXT($750MM Credit deal) FULLSTOP TEXT (JP Morgan) COMMA TEXT(Lead Bookrunner)`

Comment: Yes, this format will be constant (TEXT COMMA TEXT FULLSTOP TEXT COMMA Lead Bookrunner.)

Comment: Then it is pretty straightforward.. one moment posting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the format always be like TEXT COMMA TEXT FULLSTOP TEXT COMMA TEXT(Lead Bookrunner)? EX 1. TEXT (Uber) COMMA TEXT($9.37MM Equity) FULLSTOP TEXT (Stifel Nicolaus) COMMA TEXT(Lead Bookrunner) EX 2. TEXT (Google) COMMA TEXT($750MM Credit deal) FULLSTOP TEXT (JP Morgan) COMMA TEXT(Lead Bookrunner) – Siddharth Rout 25 mins ago

> Yes, this format will be constant (TEXT COMMA TEXT FULLSTOP TEXT COMMA Lead Bookrunner.) – ah Pl 3 mins ago

If the format is going to remain like this then it is pretty straightforward really.

**LOGIC:**

1. Look for the first `,` from left using [Instr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)
2. Look for the first `,` from right using [InStrRev](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instrrev-function)
3. Look for the first `.` from the right of the above `,` using `InStrRev`
4. Hightlight

[image]

**CODE:**

I have commented the code. If you still get stuck then feel free to leave a comment below.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lPos As Long, rPosDot As Long, rPosComma As Long, strLen As Long
    Dim cellValue As String
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find last row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Loop through the range
        For i = 1 To lRow
            With .Range("A" & i)
                '~~> Remove bold formatting
                .Font.Bold = False
                
                cellValue = .Value2
                
                If InStr(1, cellValue, "(") Then
                    .Font.Bold = True
                ElseIf InStr(1, cellValue, "Lead Bookrunner", vbTextCompare) Then
                    '~~> Store the length of the cell value
                    strLen = Len(cellValue)
                    
                    '~~> Find the position of "," from left
                    lPos = InStr(1, cellValue, ",")
                    
                    '~~> Find the position of "," from right
                    rPosComma = InStrRev(cellValue, ",", -1, vbTextCompare)
                    
                    '~~> We need this so that we can find the position of "." on the
                    '~~> right of the ","
                    cellValue = Left(cellValue, rPosComma)
                    
                    '~~> Find the position of "." from the right of ","
                    rPosDot = InStrRev(cellValue, ".", -1, vbTextCompare)
                    
                    '~~> Bold the characters
                    .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=lPos - 1).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
                    .Characters(Start:=rPosDot + 1, Length:=rPosComma - rPosDot - 1).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action:**

[image]

Comment: The sentences which show the day should be entirely in BOLD and the deals are perfectly fine(the old format). My main motto is to show weekly deals with the day heading in bold and the deals in the same way as u had suggested earlier

If you can help with this it will be great!! and my entire problem will be resolved.

Comment: Can yuo show more example of `Tuesday, September 1, 2020 (2 Public Energy Deals) Google, $750MM Credit Agreement. JP Morgan, Lead Bookrunner`

Comment: I have added the image link in the question (The HEADING CONTAINING THE DATE will always contain bracket, so if VBA to find bracket and Bold the entire line if possible)

Comment: Try it now. I have not tested the new code. if you face any issue let me know.